# Nutshell API authentication with C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to use C# to connect to the Nutshell API.

I'm unsure where the method name goes.  Is it on the URL or as part of the JSON?  I have tried both ways without success.  I know my email is valid as I have tried the same method on the nutshell website

Here is my code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.nutshell.com/v1/json/");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";


using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{\"method\": \"getApiForUsername\", \"user\":\"myemail@email.com.au\"}";

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
  var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You want your response body to look like this:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getUser","params":[],"id": "apeye"}
```

For this url:

```
https://app01.nutshell.com/api/v1/json
```

TIP: use a JSON serializer to create your JSON strings